# Dynamically choosing a view at runtime with Ember + Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using Ember, Ember Data, and Handlebars to display a timeline with a number of different types of models.  My current implementation, though functioning properly, seems like it could be drastically improved with a convention and a helper.  However, I can't figure out how to use already defined templates.

This is what I have:

```
{{#view App.AccountSelectedView contentBinding="App.selectedAccountController.everythingSorted"}}
  {{#with content}}
    <ol class="timeline">
      {{#each this}}
        {{#is constructor="App.Design"}}
        ... stuff about the design
        {{/is}}
        {{#is constructor="App.Order"}}
        ... stuff about the order
        {{/is}}
        {{#is constructor="App.Message"}}
        ... stuff about the message
        {{/is}}
      {{/each}}
    </ol>
  {{/with}}
{{/view}}
```

...along with a helper...

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('is', function(options) {
  if (this.constructor == options.hash["constructor"]) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});
```

I would rather rely on some convention to figure out what view to render.  For example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-model="App.Design" id="design-view">
... stuff about the design
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-model="App.Order" id="order-view">
... stuff about the order
</script>
```

Perhaps the data-model attribute could be used to determine how an object is rendered.

```
{{#view App.SelectedAccountView contentBinding="App.selectedAccountController.everythingSorted"}}
  {{#with content}}
    <ol class="timeline">
      {{#each this}}
        {{viewish this}}
      {{/each}}
    </ol>
  {{/with}}
{{/view}}
```

Alas, I can't figure out how to access templates from a helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('viewish', function(options) {
   // Were I able to access the templates this question
   // would be unnecessary.
   // Handlebars.TEMPLATES is undefined...
});
```

Also, is this something I should want to do with Handlebars?

Answer (score 5):

use ViewStates, see examples at:

http://jsfiddle.net/rsaccon/AD2RY/

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by establishing my own convention using a mixin.  A model corresponds to a view with a similar name.  For example, an App.Design model instance corresponds to the view App.DesignView.

```
App.ViewTypeConvention = Ember.Mixin.create({
  viewType: function() {
    return Em.getPath(this.get('constructor') + 'View');
  }.property().cacheable()
});
```

I mix this into my models...

```
App.Design.reopen(App.ViewTypeConvention);
App.Order.reopen(App.ViewTypeConvention);
```

...and iterate over a mixed collection like this:

```
{{#each content}}
  {{view item.viewType tagName="li" contentBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

This way, I avoid defining the convention explicitly in my models.  Thanks to Gordon, I realized that the view could by specified using a property on an object.  I would still really like to hear about the 'right' way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is just off the top of my head: I would create a separate template/view for each model type. E.g. there would be a `DesignView`, `OrderView`, etc. Each of these would specify the template to use with templateName (all code coffeescript):

```
App.DesignView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'design'

App.OrderView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'order'
```

All of the custom rendering for each type would be done inside the view/template.

At this point we need to have some template logic to decide which view to show for each item. The *easiest* thing to do would be to store the viewType on the model.

```
App.Design = Em.Model.extend
  viewType: App.DesignView

App.Order = Em.Model.extend
  viewType: App.OrderView
```

Then the template could look like:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="App.selectedAccountController.everythingSorted"}}
  {{view content.viewType contentBinding="content"}}
{{/collection}}
```

This is not ideal, however, since we don't want the model to know about the view layer. Instead, we could create some factory logic to create a view for a model. Then we could create a computed property on the controller which contains an array of the models and their corresponding views:

```
App.selectedAccountController = Em.ArrayController.create
  ..
  viewForModel: (model) ->
    # if model is instance of Design return DesignView, Order return OrderView etc.
  everythingSortedWithViews: ( ->
    everythingSorted.map (model) ->
      {model: model, viewType: @viewForModel(model)}
  ).property('everythingSorted')
```

The template would then look like this:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="App.selectedAccountController.everythingSortedWithView"}}
  {{view content.viewType contentBinding="content.model"}}
{{/collection}}
```

There are probably better ways to do this. I would love to hear someone who is closer to the core of Ember give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for a similar scenario.

Model 'page' hasMany 'activity'.

```
// App.PageModel
export default DS.Model.extend({
    index     : DS.attr('number'),
    activity  : DS.hasMany('activity',  { async: true })
});
```

Model 'activity' has property 'type' that references which template to use for the content in another property 'configuration'.

```
// App.ActivityModel
export default DS.Model.extend({
    activityId    : DS.attr('string'),
    type          : DS.attr('string'),
    page          : DS.belongsTo('page', { async: true }),
    configuration : DS.attr()
});
```

Note the lack of attribute type for configuration. This offers the means of storing a collection of randomly structured objects. For consistently structured objects, I suggest using [Ember-Data.Model-Fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments).

Main template:

```
{{! page.hbs }}
{{#with activity}}
    {{#each}}
        {{partial type}}
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

For type: 'static', it uses the {{{3 mustache option}}} to render a html string.

```
{{! static.hbs }}
{{{configuration.content}}}
```

The other options are far more complex, yet still simplified using a 'with'. ie: for type: 'multiplechoice',

```
{{! multiplechoice.hbs }}
{{#with configuration}}
    {{#each options}}
    <label {{bind-attr class=":label selected:checked:unchecked"}}>
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected" }}
        {{#if text.content}}
            {{{text.content}}}
        {{else}}
            {{text}}
        {{/if}}
    </label>
    {{/each}}
    {{ ...etc... }}
{{/with}}
```

With the partials, remember to consider nomenclature and/or folder structure depending on your environment, ie '_partialname.hbs' or 'viewname/partialname.hbs'